# How do I convert certain values of a 2 string array dimensional array to int and compare them with another integer in java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, parseint

I have a two dimensional array of strings and I want to convert the second column to integers and then compare each one with a number but I don't know how to do it inside a loop?

```
    int a=Integer.parseInt(array[0][1]);
    int b=Integer.parseInt(array[1][1]);
    int c=Integer.parseInt(array[2][1]);
    int d=Integer.parseInt(array[3][1]);
    int e=Integer.parseInt(array[4][1]);
    int f=Integer.parseInt(array[5][1]);
    int g=Integer.parseInt(array[6][1]);
    int h=Integer.parseInt(array[7][1]);
    int i=Integer.parseInt(array[8][1]);
    int j=Integer.parseInt(array[9][1]);


    if(number>a) return true;
    if(number>b) return true;
    if(number>c) return true;
    if(number>d) return true;
    if(number>e) return true;
    if(number>f) return true;
    if(number>g) return true;
    if(number>h) return true;
    if(number>i) return true;
    if(number>j) return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[][] array = new String[ROWSIZE][COLUMNSIZE]

for(int i = 0; i < ROWSIZE; i++){
    if(number > Integer.parseInt(array[i][1])){
      //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   if(number == Integer.parseInt(array[i][1])) {
             ...do something
    }
 }
```

this compares every row's first element to number

Answer (score 0):

Now its been a while since I've done java and i may mix in some c# accidentally, so if my syntax is incorrect i apologize

```
for(int i = 0, i = array.length, i++){
    if(Integer.parseInt(array[i][1]) == number)
    {
    //...Do code here, i.e. assign to a new array of booleans with value i beign set to true
    }
}
```

This is called a for loop.

basically, you have a value (i = 0) , you check the value does not satisfy some condition (that i is not the length of the array) and if it doesnt satisfy that condition, perform an operation, then iterate to the next value, in this case making i equal to i + 1.

This allows you to iteratively check through a list or array.

If i get any terms/syntax wrong feel free to correct me in comments or edit my post, Thanks. hopefully i answered your question